# What would the best way to clean these if statements up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I am working with a very simple **if statement tree** and want to write the code as DRY as possible, I believe I am implementing the DRYest code possible for my use case and have attempted to write in pointers to an object key *(doesn't seem possible without setter function)* and simplify the curly brackets but for purposes of the question I have left them in to make things clear on what needs to be done.

**Is there a simpler version of this if tree?**

```
let query = {};

if (min_budget || max_budget) {
    if(min_budget && max_budget) {
        query['budget.middleBound'] = { $gte: min_budget, $lte: max_budget } 
    } else if (min_budget && !max_budget) {
        query['budget.middleBound'] = { $gte: min_budget }
    } else if (max_budget && !min_budget) {
        query['budget.middleBound'] = { $lte: max_budget }
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you've checked `min_budget && max_budget` there's no reason to explicitly check for `!min_budget` or `!max_budget` subsequently.

Comment: @Pointy Yes! very helpful. I have applied the edits above thanks to you

Comment: What does `min_budget` and `max_budget` contain?

Comment: Also the outer if doesn't serve any purpose here

Comment: @CodeManiac Also true! thank you very much I have applied the edits above.

Comment: @Bdyce - Do not constantly edit your question here based on feedback (other than clarifying things that people are confused about).  Stackoverflow should be you ask a question, you get one or more answers.  You don't change the question constantly.

Comment: @Bdyce sorry my bad i missed it completely, it actually serves a purpose in case both of them are false you need not to go for any of the if else condition inside, but at the same you need one extra check every time, so i will prefer removing that,

Comment: @jfriend00 Of course, I have un-edited the question above. Thank you.

Comment: Your code creates a property on the `query` object whose name has a `.` in it. Do you really mean to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consolidating the various comments:

```
let query = {};
if (min_budget && max_budget) {
    query['budget.middleBound'] = { $gte: min_budget, $lte: max_budget }; 
} else if (min_budget) { // ***
    query['budget.middleBound'] = { $gte: min_budget };
} else if (max_budget) { // ***
    query['budget.middleBound'] = { $lte: max_budget };
}
```

Barring more domain-specific information, that's probably the simple, direct version.

You could do it with just two `if`s if you don't mind modifying an existing object:

```
let query = {};
if (min_budget || max_budget) {
    const mb = query['budget.middleBound'] = {};
    if (min_budget) {
        mb.$gte = min_budget;
    }
    if (max_budget) {
        mb.$lte = max_budget;
    }
}
```

Comment: @jfriend00 - I thought I saw a comment saying it was needed, but I sure can't see a need for it (in the top code block). Removing... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah it was me who suggested to remove the outer if, but than realized that in does have a use case ( in practical scenarios should not matter at all ) when both of the value are falsy it will not need to check the inner conditions, but i will prefer them removed :)

Comment: @Cristy - Wow, I missed the `.`!!! Fixed. :-) I wonder if the OP **really** wants a property with a `.` in it...

Comment: Just use `query.budget.middleBound` without quotes and brackets

Comment: @Train - That's up to the OP. I assume this is going to some API that expects to see the property with exactly the name they gave.

Comment: you could get more bonus points if you added another example with nested ternaries.

Comment: @Train See my answer, but it's with short-circuit not with ternaries. Ternaries are good for `if...else` statements, but we don't have `else` statements.

Comment: @Train - Not appropriate here. (I'd also argue that Cristy's `&&` version is not appropriate. `if` is the correct construct, `&&` for side-effects is just a poor idea.)

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about syntax and short code, you could make use of the [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

```
    let query = {};
    let bound = (min_budget || max_budget) && (query['budget.middleBound'] = {});
    min_budget && (bound.$gte = min_budget);
    max_budget && (bound.$lte = max_budget);
```

The idea of the code is that we first create a new `Object` at `query['budget.middleBound']` if we need to add either the min or max conditions. 
We also save a reference in `bound` and use it further (so we don't have to access again the `budget.middleBound` property on `query`, which has a long name). We still only create one extra `Object` if needed.

Note that adding properties to `Objects` after you create them is slower than creating the `Object` with all the keys already present.

It's not usually recommended to write code like this in production, as it takes more time to understand what the code does when executed.

Comment: I'm **not** a fan of using `&&` purely for side-effects. `if` is the correct construct here.

Comment: I also don't really like it here, but I like it for optional functions: `func && func();` instead of `if(func) { func(); }`